# Can we share In-app purchases across apps which belongs to same developer account?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app, skpaymenttransaction

Can we share In-app purchases across apps which belongs to same developer account ?

I have one application on App Store with a list of in-app purchases. I want to submit a new one with same code base and some theme & skin changes. Rest remain same.

In this scenario, on the app's payment page in-app purchases practically should remain same. But having a new app on App Store, it doesn't allow me to have it.

Should I be re-creating an entire list of In-app purchases for the new app ?

Also, the product identifier cannot be same across apps. So while creating new in-app purchases I will have to create products with new identifiers. This marks a big change at the back end too.

Can we pull in-app purchases of one product to the other one (belongs to same developer account) programmatically ?

Any view on this ?

Comment: No, in app purchases are linked to a single App Store app.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't share the product.

As per [documentation reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html):

> Every product is associated with a specific app. Products created for use by one app are not available in other apps. Companion apps on a different platform are different apps—the products of the Mac app are not available in the iOS app and vice versa.